# Injectivity of Homomorphism between homology of boundary and interior.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $M^{n\geq 4}$ be a compact connected manifold with connected boundary $\partial M$. Suppose
$$i_*: \pi_1(\partial M)\rightarrow \pi_1(M)$$is not injective, it means that there is non-contractible loop in $\partial M$ which is contractible in $M$.  And also we can assume this loop spans a disc $D$ in $M$, denote the small neighbourhood of $D$ in $M$ by $U(D)$. I am wondering if
$$i_*:\pi_1(\partial (M\setminus U(D)))\rightarrow \pi_1(M\setminus U(D))$$
is injective now.  I am just trying to make the non-jectivity disappear by deleting it. It looks right to me but I don't know how to rigorously explain it. Or maybe I am wrong and there is counterexample. Thanks for your help.

This is edited version by suggestions from comments.

Comment: How does injectivity on homology level tells you that the non-contractible loop in $\partial M$ is contractible in $M$? For all you know, it might still be non-contractible in $M$, but abelianization might make it trivial in homology.

Comment: Additionally, it's not clear to me how this loop spans a disc $D$. One might reason from Jordan theorem in case of surfaces, but it's not clear to me how you exhibit such a disc in case of higher dimensional manifolds.

Comment: @xyzzyz, sorry, I am not good at topology, maybe my question doesn't make sense here. I will think about  what you mentioned, thanks.

Comment: It definitely doesn’t need to bound a disk since you can have self intersections.

Comment: @ConnorMalin, Yes, it could be the case. Can I take a "good" loop in that homotopy class that bounds a disc ?

Comment: I think it can easily be done if the dimension of the boundary is at least 3. And then you can just check it can be done for 2 manifolds.

Comment: @ConnorMalin, yes, the manifold has dimension bigger or equal to 4. Why ?

Comment: Because you can easily homotope a loop to be injective if you have 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

The comments have shown that you approach does not work.

1. If $i_* : H_1(\partial M) \to H_1(M)$ is not injective, you cannot deduce that $i_* : \pi_1(\partial M) \to \pi_1(M)$ is not injective.
2. A loop in $\partial M$ which is contractible in $M$ need not span a disk in $M$.
   Take for example $M = D^2$. Then $\partial M = S^1$. Any loop in $S^1$ is contractible in $D^2$, but in general it does not span a disk $D$ in $D^2$. You cannot even find a homotopic loop for which it is true unless the loop has degree $\pm1$.
3. In the above eaxmple, you have $D = D^2$ and thus $U(D) = D^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for (1) I understand now, so I will just change the condition to that $i_*: \pi_1(\partial M)\rightarrow \pi_1(M)$ is not surjective. For (2), actually I was not claiming that every loop in that homotopic class bounds a disc. For simplicity, suppose $\pi_1(\partial M)=\mathbb{Z}$, i am wondering if there exists  a loop in this homotopic class that bounds a disc in $M$ and after the process of taking small neighbourhood, we can make the non-injectivity disappear.

Comment: You should ask a new question and make precise what are the assumptions.